# PyroCMS Minified Asset files across multiple machines

Tags: load-balancing, pyrocms, minify

If I'm deploying a site across multiple servers (to be load balanced), it seems that on one of the servers, the minified assets aren't in `assets/cache`. It's there in the other ones, but not this one. Is that a database thing that PyroCMS uses to check which asset file to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyroCMS will not check the database for cached assets, that would be weird. It just caches them whenever they are requested. Maybe traffic isn't getting to your other machine?

Comment: Turns out Pyro looks for the last modified date of assets and since I'm deploying to multiple machines, that may be different on each machine. So then I've changed the core to use file size as the hashable value.

Comment: If you have something that should be a pull request make sure you send it in.

Comment: Looks like its different in 2.3